# Выбрать класс по которому кликнули

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = function() {
        $('.open-text').click(function () {
            $('.open-block').css('display', 'block');
        })
    };
```

классов opеn-text много а открыть нужно именно по которому кликнули

Comment: вот `$(this).toggle()` и используйте

Comment: поясните, как между собой связаны эти 2 класса?

Answer (score 0):

$('.class').eq( 0 ) — первый элемент с таким классом...

$('.class').eq( 1 ) — второй элемент, и т.д.

А чтобы определить этот номер - использован `$('.open-text').index(this)` (он здесь сработает правильно при условии, что классов-text и классов-block одинаковое количество)

Здесь (this) - это элемент, на которой сработала функция (т.е. кликнутый)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.open-text', function(){
  $('.open-text').removeClass('active');
  $('.open-block').hide();

  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.open-block').eq( $('.open-text').index(this) ).show();
});
```

```css
.open-block {margin: 10px; display: none;}

.active {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="open-text">1111</button>
<button class="open-text">2222</button>
<button class="open-text">3333</button>

<div class="open-block">1111</div>
<div class="open-block">2222</div>
<div class="open-block">3333</div>
```